# Rooting for you

Tags: phrases

I have a niece who has cancer and is waiting for more results, she also has to have a painful operation to remove the cancer. I'm sending her and have sent her cards, "thinking of you" I want to say I'm rooting for her but wish that I could find a better way to say it. Any suggestions ? ( I'm not a Christian )

Comment: I can't believe someone has voted to reopen this! How much more obvious could a duplicate question be?

Comment: @FumbleFingers did you read the suggestions? They're not exactly enthralling. Seriously, would you recommend a person to send a  card to a cancer patient with the words "I'll cheer for you" or "I'll barrack for you"? I wouldn't. This question needs better suggestions.

Comment: "I'm on your side", "We're all thinking of you"...

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I've only just looked at the answers on the "original". The fact that it has only one answer (within which two out of the three suggestions are somewhat "marginal") is in principle irrelevant. But I take your point that it doesn't really help *this* OP much - I'll stick a bonus on it.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I think we must face the fact that collectively ELU isn't much interested in either the original or this duplicate question. (I cannot tell a lie - nor am I! :)  If within the next 4 hours you "ping" me with a comment against any particular answer you endorse on the "not-quite-revived" original, I'll give it the bounty. If not I'll just let the automatic bounty assignment default process deal with it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've just come out of hospital where I was recovered. I don't have a smart phone and I wasn't going to bring my precious laptop with me. But the winner of the bounty is well deserved, and I'm glad that answer has been rewarded.